# App uses a high amount of power in background

Tags: android

I have an app thats designed mostly to run in the background. The only notable things that go on is that there is pretty much a MediaRecorder running 24/7 for the microphone, and that an alarm manager is set to run some very simple (non-cpu intensive) code every 5-10 minutes (based upon user settings).

Battery usage details on my phone report the app is using about 100 mA per hour, compared to apps like Instagram and Snapchat which average about 25-30 mA per hour. Consumption level reports its responsible for 25% of my phones battery brain. And finally Power Analysis shows "CPU time used (background): 33 min, 48s, GPS running time <1s, Wi-Fi running time <1s, Kept system on for 1 min 24s."

Considering the app is designed to run 24/7 in the background, im trying to reduce power usage as much as possible. I figure apps like Instagram and Snapchat are constantly checking for new messages and would therefore be more power intensive than an app that only runs once every 5-10 minutes, but clearly thats not the case.

I do run several other threads in the background, but they're mostly used for timing and should be closed after no more than 5 seconds. Are they're any recommendations as to how to reduce the power usage?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely MediaRecorder is the culprit as it keeps media path powered on. Most well-written app are not constantly checking for new messages and events and use push notifications instead

Also, it is recommended to use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling) instead of alarm manager